# No Sound In Ubuntu 16.04!

Tags: sound, volume-control

I have noticed that this problem has been asked about many times but none of the answers that I have seen so far work for me.

Today in the morning I went to my computer and tried listening to some music but there was no sound. At first I just thought that volume was low or that it was muted but when I tried to turn up the volume it didn't work. I tried looking around the Internet for solutions but sadly nothing works.

Screen Shot of Volume menu:

[image: Click here to see the screen shot]

### Results of `fgrep -i pulse /var/log/syslog`:

```
Failed to open module /usr/lib/pulse-8.0/modules/module-bluetooth-policy.so: /usr/lib/pulse-8.0/modules/module-bluetooth-policy.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
Jul 11 14:04:09 d3faulto-comp pulseaudio[1363]: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to open module "module-bluetooth-policy".
Jul 11 14:04:09 d3faulto-comp pulseaudio[1363]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Module load failed.
Jul 11 14:04:09 d3faulto-comp pulseaudio[1363]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to initialize daemon.
Jul 11 14:04:09 d3faulto-comp pulseaudio[1360]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.
Jul 11 14:04:10 d3faulto-comp pulseaudio[1374]: [pulseaudio] ltdl-bind-now.c: Failed to open module /usr/lib/pulse-8.0/modules/module-bluetooth-policy.so: /usr/lib/pulse-8.0/modules/module-bluetooth-policy.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
Jul 11 14:04:10 d3faulto-comp pulseaudio[1374]: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to open module "module-bluetooth-policy".
Jul 11 14:04:10 d3faulto-comp pulseaudio[1374]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Module load failed.
Jul 11 14:04:10 d3faulto-comp pulseaudio[1374]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to initialize daemon.
Jul 11 14:04:10 d3faulto-comp pulseaudio[1371]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.
Jul 11 14:04:11 d3faulto-comp pulseaudio[1381]: [pulseaudio] ltdl-bind-now.c: Failed to open module /usr/lib/pulse-8.0/modules/module-bluetooth-policy.so: /usr/lib/pulse-8.0/modules/module-bluetooth-policy.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
Jul 11 14:04:11 d3faulto-comp pulseaudio[1381]: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to open module "module-bluetooth-policy".
Jul 11 14:04:11 d3faulto-comp pulseaudio[1381]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Module load failed.
Jul 11 14:04:11 d3faulto-comp pulseaudio[1381]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to initialize daemon.
Jul 11 14:04:11 d3faulto-comp pulseaudio[1378]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.
Jul 11 14:04:12 d3faulto-comp pulseaudio[1388]: [pulseaudio] ltdl-bind-now.c: Failed to open module /usr/lib/pulse-8.0/modules/module-bluetooth-policy.so: /usr/lib/pulse-8.0/modules/module-bluetooth-policy.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
Jul 11 14:04:12 d3faulto-comp pulseaudio[1388]: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to open module "module-bluetooth-policy".
Jul 11 14:04:12 d3faulto-comp pulseaudio[1388]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Module load failed.
Jul 11 14:04:12 d3faulto-comp pulseaudio[1388]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to initialize daemon.
Jul 11 14:04:12 d3faulto-comp pulseaudio[1385]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.
Jul 11 14:04:13 d3faulto-comp pulseaudio[1395]: [pulseaudio] ltdl-bind-now.c: Failed to open module /usr/lib/pulse-8.0/modules/module-bluetooth-policy.so: /usr/lib/pulse-8.0/modules/module-bluetooth-policy.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
Jul 11 14:04:13 d3faulto-comp pulseaudio[1395]: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to open module "module-bluetooth-policy".
Jul 11 14:04:13 d3faulto-comp pulseaudio[1395]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Module load failed.
Jul 11 14:04:13 d3faulto-comp pulseaudio[1395]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to initialize daemon.
Jul 11 14:04:13 d3faulto-comp pulseaudio[1392]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.
Jul 11 14:04:14 d3faulto-comp pulseaudio[1405]: [pulseaudio] ltdl-bind-now.c: Failed to open module /usr/lib/pulse-8.0/modules/module-bluetooth-policy.so: /usr/lib/pulse-8.0/modules/module-bluetooth-policy.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

Just kept on going with the same error for 6826 times.

Comment: What is the manufacturer and model  of your computer?

Comment: Manufacturer is HP and the model is a ProBook

Comment: Do you know which Probook?

Comment: Its a Probook 455 G3 Notebook

Comment: Possibly related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/700167/no-sound-on-ubuntu-15-10

Comment: No I dont think so my situation is different

Comment: Open a terminal (press Ctrl+Alt+T) and run `pavucontrol`. When a window appears, go to the `Configuration` tab. Is your audio device set to either output or duplex? Go to the `Output Devices` tab and ensure that the `Show` list at the bottom of the window is set to `All Output Devices`. Is the volume level for your audio device in that window adjustable?

Comment: @Olathe it did not work for me and when I do run pavucontrol it just opens a window and says that there is something wrong with the server.

Comment: OK, close that window, and run `rm -r ~/.config/pulse; pulseaudio -k; sleep 15; sudo service pulseaudio restart`, wait a few minutes, and test the sound. If it's still broken, run `fgrep -i pulse /var/log/syslog`, edit your question, and paste the results.

Comment: @Olathe that also didn't work well the first command doesn't work. When I run the first command I get `E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such process`

Comment: Yeah, I think the problem is that the PulseAudio server has trouble when it starts up. Try `sudo service pulseaudio restart`, wait a few minutes, then paste the results of `fgrep -i pulse /var/log/syslog` into your question.

Comment: @Olathe again just failure nothing happened when I put in the first command all what was that had me put in password and thats it nothing really did happen. When I put in the second one just failure occurred.

Comment: I hope this [sound debug wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems) helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that that there is [a bug report filed for this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1474173) which might or might not be related to Skype.

### The problem

The error message mentions that there's a problem with a PulseAudio module.

### Solution 1: disabling the module

If you'd like to try disabling the module, which might make Bluetooth audio not work, open a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), and run the following:

```
sudo sed -i 's/^load-module module-bluetooth-policy/#load-module module-bluetooth-policy/' /etc/pulse/default.pa
sudo service pulseaudio restart
sleep 15
pulseaudio -k
pulseaudio --start
pavucontrol
```

If the PulseAudio volume control shows up properly, you should have sound.

### Reenabling the module

If that doesn't fix it, open a terminal and run:

```
sudo sed -i 's/^#load-module module-bluetooth-policy/load-module module-bluetooth-policy/' /etc/pulse/default.pa
sudo service pulseaudio restart
sleep 15
pulseaudio -k
pulseaudio --start
```

### Solution 2: reinstalling the Bluetooth module

If you'd like to try reinstalling Ubuntu's version of the module, which might make Skype not work, open a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
sudo service pulseaudio restart
sleep 15
pulseaudio -k
pulseaudio --start
pavucontrol
```

If the PulseAudio volume control shows up properly, you should have sound.

Comment: sorry but it did not not the first or second solution. When I put in `pulseaudio -k` I get an erroe saying `E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such process`

Comment: Please put the results of `fgrep -i pulse /var/log/syslog` in your question. It might have a new error.

Comment: same error form last time when I run `fpreg -i pulse /var/log/syslog` the results were `Jul 11 18:21:26 d3faulto-comp pulseaudio[13229]: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to open module "module-bluetooth-policy".
Jul 11 18:21:26 d3faulto-comp pulseaudio[13229]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Module load failed.
Jul 11 18:21:26 d3faulto-comp pulseaudio[13229]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to initialize daemon.`

Comment: OK, that might be a bit different. Try the new solution 1. If it fails, see what `fgrep -i pulse /var/log/syslog` says.

Comment: whats the new solution?

Comment: I replaced solution 1 above so that it uses `sudo sed` instead of `sudo mv`. It should make it not even try to load it.

Comment: once again failure with the same error when I run `pulseaudio -k` and when I run `fgrep -i pulse /var/log/syslog` it says `Jul 11 18:21:26 d3faulto-comp pulseaudio[13229]: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to open module "module-bluetooth-policy".
Jul 11 18:21:26 d3faulto-comp pulseaudio[13229]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Module load failed.
Jul 11 18:21:26 d3faulto-comp pulseaudio[13229]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to initialize daemon.
Jul 11 18:21:26 d3faulto-comp pulseaudio[13226]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.`

Comment: Any chance this will ever be resolved?