# Login screen freezes in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, pulseaudio, hp

Everytime I boot into my freshly installed Ubuntu 16.04 in my HP Probook, the login screen freezes. I go to tty1 and see that there are some messages. here are they -

```
[360.192016] INFO: task pulseaudio:1143 blocked for more than 120 seconds
[360.192136] Not tainted 4.4.0-47-generic #68-Ubuntu
```

I think i am having issues with audio in the laptop. It freezes before the ubuntu boot sound can play. I get this error as well -

```
snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -11
snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -11
snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: azx_get_response timeout, switching to single_cmd mode: last cmd=0x01320000
snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -5
```

Sometimes it boots fine with sound. How can i fix this?

Comment: Describe your problem more briefly, either here or else where you search for help. (Also remember for the future.)

Comment: more briefly? i think its brief enough or? should i elaborate more?

Comment: d'oh... my ingrish is nott zho whell... I mean more details. Did the audio  work before, does it unfreeze after the 120s, stuff like that

Comment: ok, thanks for the clarification. it is a fresh install so it works sometimes but most of the times it does not. Now i get the error     snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -11. Updated the question as well

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer here and it works.

[No sound on Ubuntu 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/700167/no-sound-on-ubuntu-15-10)

So i created a file /etc/modprobe.d/intel.conf and added the following options -

```
options snd-hda-intel single_cmd=1
options snd-hda-intel probe_mask=1
```

And rebooted. Problem solved :)

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with Ubuntu 16.04 that often, but not always, the screen would freeze resuming from suspension only showing the following error messages: snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioc1d0 unable to sync register I followed the above solution, so far I was able to reboot successfully. I may update more if it indeed solve my problem.