# LSPCI finds my sound card but alsa and pacmd don't

Tags: drivers, sound, 18.04, pulseaudio, alsa

Title pretty much says it all. `lspci -v` finds a sound card, but neither `aplay -l` not `pacmd list-cards` don't. Problem first surfaced when updating ubuntu to 18.04, which was a hail-mary attempt to fix an another probably unrelated issue with my login screen. I'm not sure whether or not my sound was working before the ubuntu update either, since the login screen issue arose when I got my machine back from warranty repair.

Alsa self diagnose:
https://pastebin.com/787EwmQC

lspci -v:
https://pastebin.com/K52mA74m

aplay -l:
aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found...

pacmd list-cards:
0 card(s) available.

Things to note:

- My boot time lasts a bit longer than I remember it lasting, maybe some kernel module thing fails?
- My pulseaudio daemon doesn't start on boot. Maybe unrelated but I think you should know.
- I'm running the newest ubuntu (18.04).

Have tried:

- Reinstalling many things, some probably multiple times.
- Robooting with various changes
- Deleting the local pulseaudio config in `~/.config/pulse`
- reseting default.pa (might have picked the wrong one to reset to)
- Adding myself to audio group

**EDIT:** `inxi -a` sees the card and states that it's using the snd_hda_intel driver.

Comment: `snd_soc_skl: Unknown symbol snd_hdac_...`: your sound modules were not compiled correctly. You did not mention that you are not using the standard drivers.

Comment: To be completely frank, I wasn't aware of that. How do I switch back to standard drivers?

Comment: Who is administrating this machine? If it's you, try repairing (or updating) the kernel package.

Answer (score 0):

Grayfade from linux discord:

Try this, but I have no idea if it'll work:

`EDITOR=nano sudoedit /etc/modprobe.d/intel.conf`

Add these lines and save:

`options snd-hda-intel single_cmd=1
options snd-hda-intel probe_mask=1`

Reboot. If it does work, I have no idea why.

It worked, neither of us know why. Source of commands: [No sound on Ubuntu 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/700167/no-sound-on-ubuntu-15-10)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I fixed the issue blacklisting the others kernels not been used by the system.
lspci -v prompted for me on audio controller:

Kernel driver in use: sof_pci_dev
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl, sof_pci_dev

So I added on `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`:

```
blacklist sof_pci_dev
```

and comment snd_hda_intel:

```
#blacklist snd_hda_intel
```